# How to calculate $\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{m}{i}\beta^i(1-\beta)^{m-i}i^\delta=$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How to calculate $\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{m}{i}\beta^i(1-\beta)^{m-i}i^\delta=$ ? where $\beta,\delta\in[0,1],m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

PS. However, if $\delta=1$, I know that $\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{m}{i}\beta^i(1-\beta)^{m-i}i=m\beta$.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. There is a typo here, I have corrected it.

Comment: And when $\delta$ is a positive integer, it has a closed form.  But for $0 < \delta < 1$ ?? Doubtful. Maple does not even simplify the case $\beta=\delta=1/2$.